# How to encode root block elements TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

How does one encode not just the inner text provided within the textarea, but the root blocking 'p' tags as well?

My config currently looks like this

```
{
    plugins: [
        'autolink',
        'lists',
        'link',
        'image',
        'textcolor',
        'insertdatetime',
        'media',
        'table',
        'paste',
        'code',
    ],
    toolbar: 'insert | undo redo |  formatselect | bold italic backcolor  | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | table | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat',
    entity_encoding: 'named'
}
```

When I POST all html tags get encoded minus the wrapping **p** tags

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE would not (on its own) encode regular HTML tags so this is likely not a TinyMCE issue.  I would look at the framework(s) / platform you are using to see if something along the way is causing this to happen.

In my quick testing on TinyMCE Fiddle when I submit the page the posted content is simple HTML as a string with no encoding.